# Reverse scroll direction with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scroll, ionic-framework

I'm building an Ionic / Angular app and I'm in a situation that I would like to reverse the scroll direction on scroll input.
So normally when you scroll down for example the area that you scroll will also move down.
What I'm trying to accomplish is that when you scroll down the content moves up and when you scroll up the content moves down.

So is it possible to reverse the scroll direction?

This is my code:

```
 <!-- home page -->
 <script type="text/ng-template" id=“home.html">
    <ion-view ng-controller=“HomeController" title=“Home page">
        <ion-content>
            <ion-list>
                <ion-item ng-repeat="message in messages track by $index">
                    {{message}}
                </ion-item>
            <ion-list>
        </ion-content>
    </ion-view>
  </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Look at this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zanon/sxh9agvm/).

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="scrollApp">
    <scrollbox> <!-- my directive -->
        Content to be scrolled
    </scrollbox>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var app = angular.module('scrollApp', []);

app.directive('scrollbox', function($window) {

    angular.element($window).bind('mousewheel', function(event) {        

        event.preventDefault(); // cancel the default scroll

        var currentPosition = $window.pageYOffset;
        var delta = event.wheelDelta;                         
        window.scrollTo(0, currentPosition + delta);
    }); 

    return {};
});
```

Comment: Hi and thanks!, this is exactly what I was looking for but I'm not able to get it working in my project. I added my current code in my question.

Comment: @user1242574, could you please create a jsFiddle with the code that reproduces the problem? The code that you've added is not enough.

Comment: As you can see in my jsfiddle example the scroll direction is already reversed because I flipped the scroll list 180. Now I'm trying to reverse the scroll so that it acts as a normal scroll again.

Comment: Thanks for your help. You can find my new question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30576111/reverse-scroll-direction-with-180-flipped-scroll-list) Thanks!