# How to sort array in AngularJS in ng-options?

Tags: angularjs

I have this simple array:

```
$scope.myArray = ['3', '1', '2', '4'];
```

In my template, I use `ng-options` to create a select list:

```
<select ng-options="key as value for (key, value) in myArray | orderBy : '-value'"></select>
```

But sorting by `-value` does not work. How I can sort in descending order this array?

Comment: I updated the below and added a simple sort function.

Answer (score 2):

The orderBy parameter can be a property, so you likely just want:

```
<select ng-options="key as value for (key, value) in myArray | orderBy: '-toString()'">
```

See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5zc576az/11/) for an example

Comment: This is the only viable solution here. Thanks Ben, I almost lost faith in humanity, seeing the other answers…

Comment: Problem is that in array exists one symbolic value "Д". Look: http://jsfiddle.net/40xhrpj9/3/

Comment: @AlexandreNucera What doesn't work? My provided sample sorts the provided list of characters in reverse order in the select, which I think is what OP is after?

Comment: @BenHeymink, Yes you are right, my bad. He only want to reverse the array, not to sort it by value desc

Comment: I love this solution. We just need more precisions from the author of the question.

Comment: @Faud Again, you have to explain how you want to order your array. There is no natural order on the set of the numbers and the Cyrillic letters.

Comment: @Faud Blackhole is correct, we need to know HOW you would expect the sorted list to look. I imagine you will want a custom sorting function if you are mixing numbers and strings and expecting a certain outcome.

Comment: @Faud - ok, so you need to sort descending, then my solution does exactly that. It sorts the array descending, treating the data as characters. But apparently that is not what you want, so that is why we are asking you exactly HOW you would expect the output to look! Perhaps if you provide us with an example of what you expect the final data to look like, we can help :)

Comment: @Faud seriously? I've shared a solution! If it's not what you need, you NEED to provide an example of how you would expect the output to look! For example: "I have the following array: [red, blue, green] and would like it sorted to the following result: [blue, green, red]". That way we will know exactly what you require and we can help you.

Comment: [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/40xhrpj9/11/) is an updated example which sorts descending. However, it's sorting them as strings, which is what they are. If you want to treat them as numbers, but also have characters like "Д" in the array, you will need a custom sort function and know how you want the function to work.

Comment: Check please your jsfiddle, does not sort

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79431/discussion-between-ben-heymink-and-faud).

Answer (score 0):

You can use an order func.  You are using "strings" as ints.  If you truly want to do this the below will work.  If you dont you can just remove `parseInt` and use item.  I also matched your `key as value` you dont need any of that.  You can just do `value for value in data`

```
<div ng-app="myapp">
<fieldset ng-controller="FirstCtrl">
    <select 
        ng-options="key as value for (key, value) in data | orderBy :orderFunc"
        ng-model="selectedId"></select>

    {{ selectedId }}
</fieldset>
</div>
```

---

```
//js
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', []);
myapp.controller('FirstCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.data =['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'];
    $scope.orderFunc = orderFunc;
    function orderFunc(item){
        return -1 * parseInt(item, 10);
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/raLu20o9/

Comment: I'm pretty sure you actually can't use "value" variable. I mean this : " data | orderBy : '-value' " will not work right ? Since value is a ng-repeat var and the filter is applied on the global array.

Comment: I updated a fiddle and never updated the post.  Sorry

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution. The idea is to use slice() to make a copy of the array before reverse it. This way you avoid modifying you original data :

```
 <select data-ng-model="data_selected" data-ng-options="key for key in data.slice().reverse()"></select>
```

where 
`$scope.data =["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17"]`

Comment: This idea is good. I would improve it using a filter instead of doing it inline (it's more readable). If you want an exemple http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30576111/reverse-scroll-direction-with-180-flipped-scroll-list/30576470#30576470  we just need to know if it answer the question ... till we don't know the real one.

Answer (score -2):

```
{{ orderBy_expression | orderBy : expression : false}}
```

Is the solution more on https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy